# Rails appointment website - block certain timeslots/days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, database-schema

I got asked to build a website where users can make an appointment for a car testdrive.

The calendar is not limited to say, 10 days, so I cannot specify the dates beforehand. The car dealers should have the ability to block certain days or timeslots.

I came up with a Testdrive table looking something like this:

```
Testdrive
---------
- id
- user_id
- date
- timeslot
- client_title
- client_name
- client_firstname
- client_company
- client_street
- client_house_nr
- client_postal_code
- client_city
- client_email
- client_phone
- client_mobile
```

However, I'm now not sure how to model the "blocked" slots/dates thing. Was thinking of making another table like "TestdriveDate" or something, but then I'd be limiting the calendar to what's in that table... and I don't want the dealers to have to enable every day/timeslot, nor do I want to put that much data in my database. So, I guess I should have something like "BlockedDate", or "BlockedTimeSlot". In that case, however, I would have to check every date in the list on my frontend against this table.. which also doesn't feel right.

I guess the 'BlockedDate' approach would be the best way to go though? Looking for some help in modeling this so its useable for me as a developer, and for my users (the car dealers).

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
#app/models/slot.rb
class Slot < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | day | time | created_at | updated_at
   #This will be populated with all the available "slots" -- EG day 0, time 1
   enum day:  [:monday, :tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday, :friday, :saturday]
   enum time: [:0900, :1000, :1100, :1130, :1200, :1300, :1330, :1400]

   has_many :test_drives
   has_many :clients, through: :test_drives
end

#app/models/test_drive.rb
class TestDrive < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | client_id | slot_id | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :client
   belongs_to :slot
end

#app/models/client.rb
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | title | name | company | street | house_nr | postal_code | city | email | phone | mobile | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :test_drives
   has_many :slots, through: :test_drive

   def firstname
      name.split(" ").first
   end
end
```

This might be a bit overkill but it should give you the ability to do the following:

```
@client = Client.create name: "x", etc etc
@slot = Slot.find_by day: "saturday", time: "1400"

@client.test_drives.create slot: @slot
```

You'd be able to add a validation  to `test_drive` on whether a particular slot has been taken.

You'd also be able to add a validation to the `slot` model to determine which `date`/`time` combinations are permissible:

```
#app/models/slot.rb
class Slot < ActiveRecord::Base
   ... 
   validate :day_times

   private

   def day_times
      permissible_times: {monday: [:0900, :1000], tuesday: [:1200]}
      errors.add(:time, "Sorry, this time is unavailable on this day") unless permissible_times[day.to_sym].include? time
   end
end
```

You can [read up about `enum` here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

---

One of the main issues you have at the moment is that you've populated your `TestDrives` table with `client_` fields. Whilst this will work, it's a faux pas - it will quickly become cumbersome and overburdened.

You'll be much better with a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association, as described above...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understand correctly, I'd be able to block for example 10-11 on saturdays using this approach. However, what I need is more along the lines of: block timeslot x-y on specific date 10/11/2015. I suppose your approach would work if the calendar was limited in time, say 10 days, but it isn't. Thanks!

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply - I presumed the opposite from what you wrote!

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach.

### Block

- date
- timeslot

### TestDrive

- block_id
- user_id
- client_title
- client_name
- client_firstname
- client_company
- client_street
- client_house_nr
- client_postal_code
- client_city
- client_email
- client_phone
- client_mobile

A `Block` model can be created either by the car dealer or by the appointment.

For example there can be a block with `id=1`. If there is a TestDrive that has `block_id=1` then this is an appointment. If no TestDrive is found with `block_id=1` then this is just a blocked slot.

So a Block `has_one :test_drive` and a TestDrive `belongs_to :block`. A TestDrive must be associated with a Block but a Block can have no TestDrives (Zero-to-many relationship)